# Firebase SDK for Unity can only set user properties with string value?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

When I try setting a Firebase analytics user property from Unity I can [only set a string value. (Firebase documentation)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/analytics/firebase-analytics#setuserproperty)

When querying my analytics data with BigQuery I can see that the user_properties field has multiple value options (string, int, float, double):

[image: Screenshot of user properties from BigQuery]

Would love if someone that succeeded in setting a different type value or someone from Firebase can weigh in.
Is this implemented somewhere? If not, then is it planned to be implemented in the Firebase SDK for Unity?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Versions:

```
Unity 2018.2.15f1
Firebase 5.5.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: All property values in *Firebase Analytics* are strings.  *BigQuery* is making assumptions about those data types.

---

Those data types are based on the schema(s) *BigQuery* is using to try and contextualize said data. As far as *Firebase Analytics* is concerned, all user properties are strings. This is the case with the Unity SDK as well as all other Firebase Analytics SDKs; they only support strings.

[This article on BigQuery Schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas) might help a bit in understanding how they work but as a quick note, it supports [auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) of supported datatypes and this is likely why you're seeing non-string data types showing up despite not explicitly configuring them.

Comment: "All property values in Firebase Analytics are strings." What do you mean by this? When I log an event with the same Firebase Unity SDK then I can set parameters with int, float, double, and string separately. Only with set user property it doesn't allow anything other than string.

Comment: @AmosWazana All _User Properties_ are strings; _Event Parameters_ are different and can have types.

Comment: OK cool. So just to be clear: setting a user property with a string that can be parsed as an int type will be saved as user_property.value.int_value? Or will it save in user_property.value.string_value? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I am setting an integer value to a user property. However in BigQuery the value is stored in column `user_properties.value.string_value` instead of `user_properties.value.int_value`